perf record doesn't work on AMD instances on AWS
I find that perf record -g doesn't work on AMD instances on AWS. I launch a c7a.large instance with the quick start Ubuntu 24.04 AMI.
perf record -g -a -- sleep 10 doesn't record any sensible samples.
$ sudo perf record -g -a -- sleep 10
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.141 MB perf.data (1 samples) ]

$ sudo perf script -f
perf    1595 [000]   101.291513:          1 cycles:P: 
        ffffffff8598aef5 perf_ctx_enable+0x45 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff85994c30 ctx_resched+0x110 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff85994e73 __perf_event_enable+0x203 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff8599076c event_function+0x10c ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff85987424 remote_function+0x54 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff8582022e generic_exec_single+0x7e ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff858203e3 smp_call_function_single+0x103 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff8598d26d event_function_call+0x11d ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff8598d486 _perf_event_enable+0x66 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff859864ed perf_event_for_each_child+0x3d ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff8599ba38 _perf_ioctl+0x208 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff8599c018 perf_ioctl+0x48 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff85af4300 __x64_sys_ioctl+0xa0 ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff856068cb x64_sys_call+0x143b ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff867fd65f do_syscall_64+0x7f ([kernel.kallsyms])
        ffffffff86a00130 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78 ([kernel.kallsyms])
            7a4bf4724ded ioctl+0x3d (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
            5c118c216bc0 perf_evsel__ioctl+0x7b (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            5c118c216c01 perf_evsel__run_ioctl+0x3f (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            5c118c216c60 perf_evsel__enable_cpu+0x2e (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            5c118c0f5202 __evlist__enable.constprop.0+0x112 (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            5c118c06f03c __cmd_record.constprop.0+0x277c (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            5c118c0708f5 cmd_record+0xf85 (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            5c118c0dbe11 run_builtin+0x71 (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            5c118c0587df main+0x65f (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)
            7a4bf462a1ca [unknown] (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
            7a4bf462a28b __libc_start_main+0x8b (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
            5c118c058ae5 _start+0x25 (/usr/lib/linux-aws-tools-6.8.0-1012/perf)

However, perf stat seems to work
$ perf stat -e cycles:P -- sleep 10

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 10':

           2497999      cycles:P                                                              

      10.111527546 seconds time elapsed

       0.000000000 seconds user
       0.112386000 seconds sys

I check Intel instances and ARM instances, and both of them work well. Any idea on what's wrong here? Does AMD instances support perf record?
